# Ones and Twos for days

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Inspiring myself on [a recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200950/75323), we ought to compute a sequence that is very close to [A160242](http://oeis.org/A160242).

## Task

Your task is to generate the sequence \$ \{s_i\}_{i=0}^\infty \$:

`1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, ...`

Which is more easily understandable in this format:

```
      1 2 1
    1 2 2 2 1
  1 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
```

Another way to think of it is, this sequence is the concatenation of blocks \$b_i, 0 \leq i\$ where block \$b_i\$ is a `1`, followed by \$2i + 1\$ `2`s, followed by another `1`.

## Input

If your program takes input, the input is a non-negative integer `n`, telling you how far you should go in computing the sequence.

The sequence can

- be 0-indexed, so that \$s_0 = 1, s_1 = 2, s_2 = 1, ... \$
- be 1-indexed, so that \$s_1 = 1, s_2 = 2, s_3 = 1, ... \$

## Output

Your code may do one of the following:

- indefinitely print the sequence
- print/return the term `n` as given by the input
- print/return all the terms up to the term `n` as given by the input

## Test cases

(the test cases are 0-indexed)

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 1
3 -> 1
4 -> 2
5 -> 2
6 -> 2
7 -> 1
8 -> 1
9 -> 2
10 -> 2
11 -> 2
12 -> 2
13 -> 2
14 -> 1
15 -> 1
16 -> 2
17 -> 2
18 -> 2
19 -> 2
20 -> 2
21 -> 2
22 -> 2
23 -> 1
24 -> 1
25 -> 2
26 -> 2
27 -> 2
28 -> 2
29 -> 2
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest submission in bytes, wins! If you liked this challenge, consider upvoting it... And happy golfing!

Comment: If I do my answer in 1-index, can I treat the test cases as 1-indexed as well?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin of course!

Comment: You should leave the IO formats as the default rather than override them. If you meant to re-iterate the defaults, then you left a couple out (like a few of the options for functions)

Comment: @JoKing I was pretty confident I had seen a fair share of sequence challenges where the 3 standard outputs were these. What did I leave out?

Comment: I may be taking `indefinitely print the sequence ` too literally, but the tag wiki for [tag:sequence] allows returns an infinite lazy iterator/generator

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>25 24</s>  23 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th term, 1-indexed.

```javascript
n=>n>(++n**.5|0)**2?2:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoMwDADQq@QzaTVYhz9CK55jjFE6FUXTUocg7O7de5u//Bnymr61xM9UZlvEOnGotSjF3a8hpdqh7U0JUc64T7zHBZ/MPObsb3w09OLDJ8R3BUJgHcwooMEQUfkD)

#### How?

We have \$a(n)=2\$ iff the difference between \$n+1\$ and the previous square is greater than \$1\$:

$$n+1-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n+1}\right\rfloor^2>1$$

which boils down to:

$$n>\left\lfloor \sqrt{n+1}\right\rfloor^2$$

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
,‘Æ²E‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/nUcOMw22HNrkC6f9GBkGH2x81rfkPAA)

## Explanation

```
,‘Æ²E‘  Main Link:                  N
,       pair with
 ‘                increment         [N, N + 1]
  Æ²    is it a square?             [issq(N), issq(N + 1)]
    E   are both equal (N and N+1 cannot both be square, so if one is square, it will return 0, and if both are not square, it will return 1)
     ‘  increment (if N or N+1 is square, return 1; otherwise, return 2)
        (implicit input)
```

Comment: 1 indexing is fine, Ty for your comment.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:2-(-n%n**.5<.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfbhvzPycxNyklUSHPykhXQzdPNU9LS8/URs9U839afpFCnkJmnkJRYl56qoahjomBphUXZ0FRZl6JQp6OQrpGnuZ/AA)

Outputs the \$n\$'th value one-indexed.

We use an arithmetic expression to identify indices `n` that are either perfect square or one below a perfect square. To do so, we use a measure that's roughly of the distance between `n` and the next perfect square, given by `-n%n**.5`.

For squares, we have `-n%n**.5==0` because `n` is an even multiple of its square root, that is for `n=k*k`, `-(k*k)%k==0`. If `n` is one less than a perfect square, then the remainder is `<0.5`, if it's two less, it's be between `0.5` and `1`, and so on. So, the condition `-n%n**.50.5` accepts only perfect squares and numbers one less.

Comment: This gives the wrong output for n=8, 15, 24,...

Comment: @PoonLevi Thanks, that's embarrassing I missed that.

Comment: Fixed and undeleted

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 31 bytes

```python
i=0
while i:=100*i+121:print(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9PWgKs8IzMnVSHTytbQwEArU9vQyNCqoCgzr0QjU/P/fwA)

Print the sequence infinitely, with a questionable format.

The following version output the first `n` terms of the sequence:

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda n:"".join(f"{1:2<{-~i*2}}1"for i in range(n))[:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSklJLys/M08jTana0MrIplq3LlPLqLbWUCktv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNPUzPaKi/2f0FRZl6JRpqGgaYmF4xtiMxGkTAA8v4DAA)

**Input**: Non-negative integer `n`

**Output**: the first `n` terms of the sequence, concatenated into a string.

**Explanation**

A different approach using only string formatting instead of @Arnauld's closed-form formula.

- `f"{1:2<{x}}1"` evaluates to `"122..21"` with `x-1` characters `"2"`. (The first `"1"` is left justified to a block of width `x`, with `"2"` being the fill character).
- `-~i*2` is equivalent to `(i+1)*2`

Thus `f"{1:2<{-~i*2}}1"` evaluates to the string `"122..21"` with `i*2+1` characters `"2"`.

Comment: I like your 31 byter a lot! Really clever way of building the sequence.

Comment: You can get rid of the questionable format by adding `,end=''`.

Comment: @L.F. yeah... but that will takes more bytes on something not absolutely necessary. I'd prefer keeping the format as it is if it saves some characters.

Comment: now 3.8 is stable.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Giuseppe

```r
1+all((scan()+1:2)^.5%%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/31A7MSdHQ6M4OTFPQ1Pb0MpIM07PVFXVUPO/kfF/AA)

Uses the fact that \$s_n=1\$ iff \$n+1\$ or \$n+2\$ is a perfect square.

Comment: [26 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K/r/31A7MSdHo7iwqESjODkxT0NT29DKSFNV1VDzv9l/AA)

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks! I found an extra byte to golf, down to 25.

Answer (score 4):

## Symja, <s>38</s> 33 bytes

```
f(x_):=If(Mod(-(x^.5),1)*x<1,1,2)
```

[Y'all can try it here](https://symjaweb.appspot.com/input?i=f%28x%5f%29%3a%3dIf%28Mod%28%2d%28x%5e%2e5%29%2c1%29%2ax%3c1%2c1%2c2%29%3b%20f%2829%29)

This is just a port of xnor's (who helped me save 5 bytes) Python 2 answer in Symja. This took a while to generate, as I had to properly understand what the formula was, due to operator precedence. Anyhow, enjoy!

Comment: I dunno Symja, but I'd guess you could replace the `2-` by putting the resulting values in as the outcomes of the `If`. Also, it doesn't lok like you need parens after the `*x`.

Comment: @xnor You're right. The brackets must have been from failed attempts at porting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/): 52 bytes

```
def g(n):return(2,1)[not((n+1)**.5%1and(n+2)**.5%1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcw7CoAwEAXA2pwijbCrIiRgoVcRCyEf07zIEgtPHxUsp5nzLkeGrdX5oCOBF/HlEpAdDK/IhQi94a4bp9bscK/sL95qyKKhE7TsiJ7szItqTkko9F1c1QM)

Returns the nth term in the sequence.
Also using the fact that the nth term = 1 <=> (n+1) or (n+2) is square as Robin Ryder pointed out.

Comment: You can use `lambda` to get rid of `return` statement, and `2-i` instead of `(2,1)[i]`. [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfbhvzPycxNyklUSHPykhXIy@/REMjT9tQU0tLz1TVMDEvBcgzgvI0Nf@n5Rcp5Clk5ikUJealp2oYWWpacXEWFGXmlWika@QBFXABAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 67 bytes

This answer returns the entire sequence up to the requested value.

```apl
f←{(⊃,/1,¨⌽¨1,¨2⍴⍨¨1+2×1-⍨⍳1+⌈⍟⍵)[⍳⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqjUddzTr6hjqHVjzq2XtoBYhh9Kh3y6PeFUCOttHh6Ya6QPaj3s2G2o96Oh71zn/Uu1UzGsgH0rG1QEMUDLnSFIyA2BiITYDYFIgNDUAEiGUEYhmBWMYglrEpAA)

Decomposition/Explanation:

```apl
f←                                     ⍝ assign the name f to
  {                                  } ⍝ a dfn that takes a single argument
                              ⍟⍵       ⍝ The natural logarithm of the argument,
                             ⌈         ⍝ rounded up to the next integer,
                           1+          ⍝ and add 1 (giving N), then
                          ⍳            ⍝ generate the sequence 1..N,
                       1-⍨             ⍝ and subtract 1 from each term (0..N-1)...
                                       ⍝    ⍨ means to swap the arguments to
                                       ⍝    - (the standard subtraction function), so
                                       ⍝    1-⍨N is the same as N-1.
                     2×                ⍝ ... then multiply each term in the sequence by 2,
                   1+                  ⍝ and add 1
                  ¨                    ⍝ then take each term in the sequence, and
               2⍴⍨                     ⍝ generate a vector of that many 2s
                                       ⍝    ⍨ means to swap the arguments to
                                       ⍝    ⍴ the "shape" function. For simple numeric
                                       ⍝    values of A and B, A⍴B means to generate a 
                                       ⍝    vector of A repeats of B.
                                       ⍝ We now have a vector of vectors of 2s.
              ¨                        ⍝ For each of those vectors,
            1,                         ⍝ prepend a 1, then
           ¨                           ⍝ for each vector, 
          ⌽                            ⍝ reverse it (so that the 1 is on the 'back end'), then
       1,¨                             ⍝ for each (now reversed with a 1) vector, prepend a 1, and
     ,/                                ⍝ concatenate all the vectors. For reasons I don't quite
                                       ⍝    understand, this generates an enclosed object, so
    ⊃                                  ⍝ unenclose (disclose) it into a 'real' vector, and
   (                            )      ⍝ treat all that as an object...
                                 [  ]  ⍝ ...which can be subscripted. If the subscript is
                                       ⍝    a single integer, it will return just that item from
                                       ⍝    the array; if it's a vector, it will return all of the
                                       ⍝    requested values, in the order specified by the vector.
                                  ⍳⍵   ⍝ This subscript is a vector, of the integers 1 to the original
                                       ⍝    argument to the function, so it will generate the entire
                                       ⍝    sequence up to the ⍵th term. If I only wanted the single
                                       ⍝    term, I would omit the ⍳, which would give me only the ⍵th term.
```

FIRST GOLFING (courtesy ngn):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 65 bytes

```apl
f←{⍵↑(⊃,/1,¨⌽¨1,¨2⍴⍨¨1+2×1-⍨⍳1+⌈⍟⍵)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71bH7VN1HjU1ayjb6hzaMWjnr2HVoAYRo96tzzqXQHkaBsdnm6oC2Q/6t1sqP2op@NR73ygNs1aoBEKhlxpCkZAbAzEJkBsCsSGBiACxDICsYxALGMQy9gUAA)

Explanation of golfing:

```apl
[⍳⍵] is the same as [1 2 3 4 5 6 ... ⍵], 
      which is the first ⍵ items of the vector being subscripted.
      That's the same as 
⍵↑    "Take" the first ⍵ items.  Savings, 2bytes.
```

SECOND GOLFING (my own discovery):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 63 bytes

```apl
f←{⍵↑⊃,/1,¨⌽¨1,¨2⍴⍨¨1+2×1-⍨⍳1+⌈⍟⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71bH7VNfNTVrKNvqHNoxaOevYdWgBhGj3q3POpdAeRoGx2ebqgLZD/q3Wyo/ain41HvfKCuWqABCoZcaQpGQGwMxCZAbArEhgYgAsQyArGMQCxjEMvYFAA)

Explanation of golfing: The expression that was formerly subscripted does not need to be parenthesized if using `⍵↑` instead of `[⍳⍵]`. Savings, 2bytes.

Comment: [-13 chars](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HXokdtEx91zHjU0VVtqPOod4WhjtGj3i1AxqH1htpGh6c/6t1ae2gFSEXv5v9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGIN19U4ODnIFkiIdn8P80BUOuNAUjIDYGYhMgNgViQwMQAWIZgVhGIJYxiGVsCgA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 23 bytes

```powershell
for(){$i++;1;,2*$i++;1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SEOzWiVTW9va0FrHSAvCqv3/HwA)

Prints the sequence indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```perl6
{flat (1,2,2 xx$++*2,1)xx*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Oi0nsURBw1DHSMdIoaJCRVtby0jHULOiQqv2f3FipUKahmZ0nJFB7H8A)

Anonymous codeblock returning a lazy infinite list. I wish I could do `2 xx++$++` or some combination of it, but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 16 bytes

Port of Surculose Sputum's Python answer.

```
0{100*121+.p.}do
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/36Da0MBAy9DIUFuvQK82Jf//fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
i=1
while 1:print('1'+'2'*i+'1');i+=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9PWkKs8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69EQ91QXVvdSF0rUxvI0rTO1LY1@v8fAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>14 12</s></sup> 10 bytes

```
ṁ`Jḋ3MRİ12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxgSvhzu6jX2DjmwwNPr/HwA)

Infinite list.

-1 byte from Dominic Van Essen.

-2 bytes from Zgarb using voodoo magic.

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HORo0EK0Mrw4QgI80jGwz//wcA) I think...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen that works with ȯ. nice.

Comment: Ah yes!  Well spotted.

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxgSvhzu6jX2DjmwwNPr/HwA). It was a bit challenging to get `J` to choose the right type...

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```c
i,c;main(){main(i--<-2?i=c+=2:putchar(49+(c+~i&&i+3)));}
```

*-1 byte thanks to [RGS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75323/rgs)!*
*-8 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ9k6NzEzT0OzGkxl6ura6BrZZ9oma9saWRWUliRnJBZpmFhqayRr12WqqWVqG2tqalrX/v8PAA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 46 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=0;n--;)printf("%d",i=i*100+121);}
```

Stretches the rules and only works up to \$n=4\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEADAu68QIditBI1ui48JxdhDGhJdpLdvznWiPWMUYcpQsOfagIOjYi3h3bg8GcyUzMqBZ@/c4jeP9MkIfR1c4K2cUHWlhww7kvrkBw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
If[#==1||(d=NumberQ@*Sqrt)@#||d[#+1],1,2]&
```

returns 1 if n=1 or n is a perfect square or n+1 is a perfect square

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zMtWtnW1rCmRiPF1q80Nym1KNBBK7iwqETTQbmmJiVaWdswVsdQxyhW7X9AUWZeiYJDerSRSSwXgmMZ@/8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
>‚Å²Ë>
```

Port of [*@HyperNeutrino*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200991/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

Outputs the result for the 1-based input \$n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7lHDrMOthzYd7rb7/98cAA) or [verify all the first \$n\$ outputs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/e/qd3iCvZLCo7ZJCkr2/@0eNcw63Hpo0@Fuu/86/w0NDAA).

Printing the infinite sequence is **<s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/codepage)** (based on the 6-byter above):

```
∞ü‚Å²€Ë>
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9vc2FiaWX//@KInsO84oCaw4XCsuKCrMOLPv//)

Previous **9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/codepage)** variations for the infinite sequence:

- `Y∞иXδš€û˜`: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9vc2FiaWX//1niiJ7QuFjOtMWh4oKsw7vLnP//)
- `ÅÉÅ2Xδ.ø˜`: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOvhzsOtRhHntugd3nF6zv//AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
>         # Increase the (implicit) input-integer by 1
 ‚        # Pair it with the (implicit) input-integer: [input, input+1]
  Å²      # Check for both whether they're a square (which will be either both falsey,
          # or just one of the two is truthy)
    Ë     # Check if both are equal (so both falsey) (1 if truhy; 0 if falsey)
     >    # And increase that by 1 (2 if truthy; 1 if falsey)
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)

∞         # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ü‚       #  Pair each overlapping pair together: [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],...]
   Å²     # Check for each whether it's a square
     €Ë   # Check for each pair whether they're equal
       >  # Increase it by 1
          # (after which it is output implicitly as result)              

 ∞        # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
Y и       # Repeat a 2 that many times as list: [[2],[2,2],[2,2,2],...]
    δ     # For each inner list:
   X š    #  Prepend a 1: [[1,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2,2],...]
      €   # For each inner list:
       û  # Palindromize it: [[1,2,1],[1,2,2,2,1],[1,2,2,2,2,2,1],...]
        ˜ # Flatten the list of lists: [1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,...]
          # (after which it is output implicitly as result)

ÅÉ        # Push all odd numbers equal to or less than the given argument,
          # which will be an infinite sequence without argument: [1,3,5,...]
  Å2      # Create for each value a list with that many 2s: [[2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2],...]
     δ    # For each inner list:
    X .ø  #  Surround it with 1s: [[1,2,1],[1,2,2,2,1],[1,2,2,2,2,2,1],...]
        ˜ # Flatten the list of lists: [1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,...]
          # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
↷²1Ｗ¹«2Ｐ1Ｄ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gsyy/JCgzPaNEw0jTmiugKDOvREPJUAnILs/IzElV0DDUVKjm4oRKGIEkOH1Lc0oyC5CUcrqU5hZogBjI6mr///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Prints the infinite sequence. Explanation:

```
↷²
```

Change the default direction to downwards, so that everything now prints vertically by default.

```
1
```

Output `1` to the canvas.

```
Ｗ¹«
```

Loop forever.

```
2
```

Output `2` to the canvas.

```
Ｐ1
```

Output `1` to the canvas, but don't move the cursor.

```
Ｄ
```

Copy the canvas to STDOUT.

```
2
```

Replace the `1` with a `2`.

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 18 bytes

```
?d2+vd*rvd*-d/2r-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@xUi7LEWrCIh1U/SNinQL/v83BwA)

This uses 0-based indexing, and it computes the *n*<sup>th</sup> value in the sequence for index *n*.  Input is on stdin, and output is on stdout.

It computes $$2 -K_{\neq0}\big(\lfloor{\sqrt{n+2}}\rfloor-\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor\big),$$ where \$K_{\neq0}\$ is the function that maps 0 to 0, and any non-zero number to 1.  (\$K_{\neq0}\$ isn't built into dc, but you can compute it by dividing a number by itself, as long as you're careful with the stack when its argument is 0.)

There may be spurious output on stderr (due to division by 0).

Here's a [TIO link to the test suite](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifkuycn5JqG/PfPsVIuyxFqwiIdVP0jYp0C/6n5Rcp5Clk5ilUG@jpGVnWWiuk5HMpKCikJmfkK@jmKSip5CnY2ikogcRSkhV0U4EiEPOUbGxsgLJKXCn5ean/AQ).

Answer (score 2):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

The long length doesn't really matter to me. W doesn't have a square-checking built-in.

```
φßéW!r♀
```

Uncompressed:

```
){Q1m!=r)
```

### Explanation

```
)         % Increment the input. [input + 1]
 {        % Pair with the input. [input, input + 1]
  Q       % Find the square root.[sqrt(input), sqrt(input + 1)]
   1m     % Modulo 1. (Find the digits after the decimal point.)
     !    % Are the digits 0? (True, it's a square number. Otherwise,
          % it can't be a square number.)
      =r  % Reduce by equality.
        ) % Increment the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 55 bytes

```powershell
$i=0;1.."$args"|%{$i+=2;write-host "1,$('2,'*$i)1," -n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXT1sDaUE9PSSWxKL1YqUa1WiVT29bIurwosyRVNyO/uERByVBHRUPdSEddSyVT01BHSUE3r/b///9mAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>80</s> 75 bytes

```c
j,k=1;main(int a,char**b){for(a=atoi(b[1]);j<a;k+=2,j+=k);return(1<j-a)+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExEoMgEAXQq6QEgQJTrpzESfFl1AC6ziBWjlfP5r3o4gZeRbItwdOOxCpxe8HGL2rXTfpejqoQ0I6kptF/NOUBVEzobTahaKpzuyorP2QHbTw9IvL@xWXDeooDn@kP)

This one takes an input N at the terminal and returns the Nth value.  This is zero-indexed.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>48</s> 44 bytes

```c
j,k=1;f(a){for(;j<a;k+=2,j+=k);a=(1<j-a)+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBDoIwEETvfMWGhKSlbQJ63NYv8bKWFLdoMeCN8OtWQN9tJm/Gm977nKMeXItBkFzCOAmMlnBQ7qSjcoNEcqK10ZBULa75SZwEpzeQ9nea6vomlwI29o7BQYNHPJ7YnhtUiv/KzmvaxCDKqgNzgaq7plIDawiCpfxN12LNHx8e1M/ZUJr5Cw)

Same basic function here, but modified to just be a function to not take the hit from main's arg-list and converting a string to an integer.  Switched over to GCC to take advantage of undefined behavior that avoids need for explicit return.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to this community! Can you please provide a [TIO link](https://tio.run) with your code?

Comment: @RGS Added TIO.

Comment: Thanks, nice first post!

Comment: Suggest `j+=k+=2` instead of `k+=2,j+=k`

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYzBDoIwEETvfMWGhKSlNKF6XMqXeFlLiptqMcUb4detVH23mbwZp2fncg7oBcnNL0kEa9AMhKRtUPYkkazoR5LK4J4fxFFwfAF17kapba9yq@CgdAwWDH5jOUIezj0qxX@l8EyH6EXdTKBHaKZLrDvgDrxgKX/Tvdrz2/k7zWvWFFf@AA) by removing `j` and using 1-based indexing.

Comment: @ceilingcat Ah, good catch for golfing the algorithm without changing it.

Comment: @Bubbler When I have time, I have a couple questions about how your changes work.  For starters, though, I'm curious why the `k=1` assignment is necessary in the for-loop rather than initialization.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons the `k=1` assignment needs to be moved so the function can be called again.

Comment: Oh, right, I was still in the mind-space of my original design that didn't separate it out into its own function.

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP 0.0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 16 bytes

```
[1:![2:1A]%1:2M]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>39</s> 34 bytes

```python
i=1
while 1:print(1,*[2]*i,1);i+=2
```

Prints the sequence infinitely. Thanks to @SurculoseSputum for saving me 5 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9PWkKs8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69Ew1BHK9ooVitTx1DTOlPb1uj/fwA)

Comment: I forgot that printing the sequence infinitely is an option... [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9PWkKs8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69Ew1BHK9ooVitTx1DTOlPb1uj/fwA)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9PWkKs8IzMnNbqgKDOvRMNQRyvaKFYrU8dQM9YqU9vW6P9/AA) by using the print statement as conditional

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>64</s> <s>61</s></sup> 41 bytes

Saved 20 bytes thanks to [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne)!!!

```bash
s=2;while :;do echo 1 $s 1;s+=' 2 2';done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9jWyLo8IzMnVcHKOiVfITU5I1/BUEGlWMHQuljbVl3BSMFIHSiRl/r/PwA)

Infinitely prints the sequence.

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9jWyLo8IzMnVcHKOiVfITU5I1/BUEGlWMHQuljbVl3BSMFIHSiRl/r/PwA) you don't need the quotes for bash strings without spaces, and some other major fixes

Comment: [maybe 37](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9jWyLo8IzMnVcHKOiVfITU5I1/BUKW6uNbQuljb1sgIKJiX@v8/AA)

Comment: @S.S.Anne Yeah, was trying to get at it from the wrong angle (originally `printf` with string padding) . Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -lm, <sup><s>57</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>52</s></sup> 50 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
t;s(n){t=sqrt(n);n=n!=t*t;};f(n){n=1+s(n)*s(n+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsMgEEX3OcU0EHBiXFjoamJP0k0wGAaSaavuglevNZvP473vzeZ9rZmSEjyzS9@YG5E4ubk8ZioUriLO6usyttEWqdRjYVF4dhDeUbFkYGeJ5/uDtGb8xKaC6ocVzBOG9SX9BDxBUIxIXak/H/ZlS9Xsxx8)

Returns the nth term in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck, 72

```
+++++++[>+++++++<-]>[>+>+<<-]>>+[<.>>+[>+>+<<-]>[<<.>>-]>[<<+>>-]<<<<.>]
```

Might be able to make it shorter but here's my shot. Prints indefinetly

1. Initialize first two cells with (ASCII values for) 1 and 2
2. Start a loop (looping on the 2 cell but it doesn't really matter)

   1. Print the 1
   2. Increase the count, and then copy the count to the next two cells
   3. Use one of the counts to print the twos (decreases the count until 0, then exits loop)
   4. Copy the second copy of the count back to where it was before
   5. Print a final 1

Comment: Can you please provide a TIO link?

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20YXBGLtdEEcINcGyLbTjrbRA5FwkWgbkACEoQ1i2NiARGL//wcA) using [Brainfuck constants](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants).

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20YXBGLtdHWVo/W07bSjdYFiNnp2sdp20bo22naxNja6erH//wMA) by just using 1 cell for ASCII 1

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 + 1 (-p) = 36 bytes

```perl
$_=(map{(1,2,(2,2)x$_,1)}0..$_)[$_]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYjN7GgWsNQx0hHw0jHSLNCJV7HULPWQE9PJV4zWiU@9v9/I8t/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Reads input `n` from stdin. Simplisticly builds a list of the first at least `n` elements (actually the first `2n+3` elements), then prints the `n`th element.

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 + 1 (-p) = 31 bytes

```perl
$_=$_+1>(($_+2)**0.5|0)**2?2:1
```

Smarter and more efficient way of doing it with Arnauld's formula from above (but adjusted to be 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed, because that's how I like it).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYlXtvQTkMDSBlpamkZ6JnWGABpI3sjK8P//40s/@UXlGTm5xX/1y0AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [dirt](https://github.com/0xB0C5/dirt) (verbose mode), 17 bytes

```
"1
2
1"|1"
2
2".*
```

Run as `dirt ones_and_twos.dirt -v -i ""`

Outputs each element of the sequence on a new line.

Alternatively, if we allow new lines between some but not all elements,

### dirt (verbose mode), questionable format, 13 bytes

```
"121"|1"22".*
```

prints

```
121
12221
1222221
122222221
12222222221
1222222222221
122222222222221
12222222222222221
...
```

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 21 bytes

```
_+(Tr$)%1)=Tr_+$)%1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/P15bI6RIRVPVUNM2pCheG8zS/P8fAA)

Port of the jelly answer.

### Explanation

```
    r$)     r_+$)     # Root (defaults to square root)
       %1        %1   # Modulo 1 (only taking the decimal part)
   T     ) T       )  # Ceiling (round up if there is a decimal part)
  (       =         ) # Equal (same as jelly answer)
_+                    # Successor (same as jelly answer)
```

## List output, 15 bytes

```
1,D2)*_-(k*2),1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/31DHxUhTK15XI1vLSFPH8P9/AA)

Playing with the output a bit, we can golf off 6 bytes.

Instead of outputting `1,2,2,2,1`, it outputs `1,[2,2,2],1`.

### Explanation

```
1,              # A one
  D2)           # Digits of 2 (which is of course, just 2)
     *_-(k*2)   # Multiplied by k*2-1 (it's multiplying a list)
             ,1 # Another one
```

Comment: Why is it cheating?

Comment: It outputs a list instead of outputting the sequence. It only works for indefinitely printing, whereas other normal cQuents code could work for all 3 cases (the third requiring an &).

Comment: Indefinite printing is fine but the lists in the middle of the numbers look weird

Comment: Hold on, I just found the jelly answer. Gonna port.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 36 bytes

```hs
do n<-[0..];'1':([1..n]>>"22")++"21"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPyVfIc9GN9pATy/WWt1Q3Uoj2lBPLy/Wzk7JyEhJU1tbychQ6X9uYmaebUFpSXBJkYKKQklidqqCqYFC2v9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

This expression evaluates to an infinite string.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 31 bytes

Prompts for integer. Index origin=1
Returns single term of the series.

```
2 1[1++/m=1,(n+1),n←+\1+2×⍳m←⎕]
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4bKRhGG2pr6@faGupo5GkbaurkASW1Ywy1jQ5Pf9S7ORfIA2qJ/Q9U/T@Ny5ArjcsIiI2B2ASITRWAhBmIMAdiCyC2BGJDAxABUmsIUmxoDFJgCFJvaAoA)

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 51 Bytes

`f n=concat['1':['2'|x<-[0..y*2]]++"1"|y<-[0..n]]!!n`

Comment: Not very competitive, but I thought that I would provide a  Haskell solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
Count[√#+√(#+1),_@__]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zm/NK8k@lHHLGVtIKGhrG2oqRPvEB8fq/Y/oCgTKKWsa5fmoByrVhecnJhXF5SYl57qYGLw/z8A)

1-indexed.

```
√#+√(#+1)           (* sqrt(n)+sqrt(n+1) *)
Count[ % ,_@__]     (* count nonatomic subexpressions at the first level. *)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
do n<-[1..];show$div(100^n)9*11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPyVfIc9GN9pQTy/Wujgjv1wlJbNMw9DAIC5P01LL0PB/bmJmnm1BaUlwSZGCikJJYnaqgqmBQtr/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

**32 bytes**

```hs
show=<<iterate(\x->x*100+121)121
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzvzgjv9zWxiazJLUosSRVI6ZC165Cy9DAQNvQyFATiP/nJmbm2RaUlgSXFCmoKJQkZqcqmBoopP3/l5yWk5he/F83uaAAAA)